# javascript array sort 2d array on first column only

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i've checked a bunch of solutions on this but none seem to help out.

here is my array in Javascript

```
[
{"1/2/2015",344},
{"1/3/2015",444},
{"1/2/2015",544},
{"1/3/2015",44},
{"1/2/2015",34},
{"1/3/2015",340}
]
```

i want this to be sorted on the first column (date) without sorting by the second column (count) as well (i.e. maintaining the current order on the count for a given date). The javascript sort() function seems to sort by date and then sort by count which is undesirable. The desired output is

```
[
{"1/2/2015",344},
{"1/2/2015",544},
{"1/2/2015",34},
{"1/3/2015",444},
{"1/3/2015",44},
{"1/3/2015",340}
]
```

any pointers to get this solved is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Pass a custom sort function to `sort()`.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid javascript - the objects in the array are incorrect (they need a `{ key:value, ... }` format, but you are using `{value, value}`)

Comment: your array should be `[
["1/2/2015",344],
["1/2/2015",544],
["1/2/2015",34],
["1/3/2015",444],
["1/3/2015",44],
["1/3/2015",340]
]
`?

Comment: Or maybe `[ { date: "1/2/2015", count:344} , ... ]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct: the inner objects are not valid. In comments you specified you have inner arrays, so then they need square brackets instead of braces.

The solution could be to create a copy and add the original array index to the data, then do a custom sort that takes this index as secondary sort criterion, and then drop that index from the final result:

```js
var data =  [ ["10/02/2015",3351], ["10/03/2015",7273], ["10/04/2015",8609], ["10/05/2015",8941], ["10/06/2015",7493], ["10/07/2015",8030], ["10/08/2015",10545], ["10/02/2015",335], ["10/03/2015",727], ["10/04/2015",860], ["10/05/2015",894], ["10/06/2015",749], ["10/07/2015",803], ["10/08/2015",1055], ["10/02/2015",1351], ["10/03/2015",1273], ["10/04/2015",1609], ["10/05/2015",1941], ["10/06/2015",1493], ["10/07/2015",1030], ["10/08/2015",1545] ];

data = data.map( (o, i) => [o, Date.parse(o[0]), i] )
    .sort( (a, b) => a[1] - b[1] || a[2] - b[2] )
    .map ( a => a[0] );
    
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

On a final note: make sure your dates are [formatted correctly to be understood by the `Date.parse` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

I would strongly suggest to use the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD` in your strings to avoid misinterpretations.

Comment: Sorry i meant to use the latter syntax. When i try to run the code with the following data set, i get incorrect results though.  
[
["10/02/2015",3351],
["10/03/2015",7273],
["10/04/2015",8609],
["10/05/2015",8941],
["10/06/2015",7493],
["10/07/2015",8030],
["10/08/2015",10545],
["10/02/2015",335],
["10/03/2015",727],
["10/04/2015",860],
["10/05/2015",894],
["10/06/2015",749],
["10/07/2015",803],
["10/08/2015",1055],
["10/02/2015",1351],
["10/03/2015",1273],
["10/04/2015",1609],
["10/05/2015",1941],
["10/06/2015",1493],
["10/07/2015",1030],
["10/08/2015",1545]
];

Comment: I tried your data, and included it in my answer: it seems the result is OK. What is wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't use *Date.parse* at all given it's inconsistency. There's no need for either *map*, you just need *sort*: `data.sort((a,b)=>Date.parse(a[0]) - Date.parse(b[0]))`.

Comment: @RobG, `Date.parse` is consistent when used with ISO date format (like I suggested in my answer). Also note that `sort` will often visit the same values multiple times, so pre-processing with `map` -- which visits each value only once -- will at some point give a time-advantage on larger arrays. In general it is better to move work from the *O(nlogn)* part of the algorithm to a part that is *O(n)*.

Comment: And: if you only use `sort` like you mentioned (without `map`), there is no guarantee that the original order will be maintained in case of equal dates. See [EcmaScript specs on this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort): *"elements that compare equal do not necessarily remain in their original order"*.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need something to reliably parse the date strings. You can use a library but a simple function is 2 lines (assuming the dates are valid). Then use a sort function:

```js
// Parse date string in format d/m/y
function parseDMY(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[2],b[1]-1,b[0]);
}

var data = [
["1/2/2015",344],
["1/3/2015",444],
["1/2/2015",544],
["1/3/2015",44],
["1/2/2015",34],
["1/3/2015",340]
];

console.log(data.sort(function(a, b){
  return parseDMY(a[0]) - parseDMY(b[0]);
}));
```

Comment: the solution appears to work for the sample data above but fails to fully sort properly when the data is like below.
[
["10/02/2015",3351],
["10/03/2015",7273],
["10/04/2015",8609],
["10/05/2015",8941],
["10/06/2015",7493],
["10/07/2015",8030],
["10/08/2015",10545],
["10/02/2015",335],
["10/03/2015",727],
["10/04/2015",860],
["10/05/2015",894],
["10/06/2015",749],
["10/07/2015",803],
["10/08/2015",1055],
["10/02/2015",1351],
["10/03/2015",1273],
["10/04/2015",1609],
["10/05/2015",1941],
["10/06/2015",1493],
["10/07/2015",1030],
["10/08/2015",1545]
];

Comment: It works for me. Note that I assume that your date format is day/month/year, not the peculiar US month/day/year.

Comment: Agreed on the *peculiar*. ;-)

Comment: seems to work now as well. not sure what was wrong then.